# How to process missing commit

Tags: jgit

Now I an using JGit to store some information for my git repository. 
First I create a empty bare repository.

```
Git.init().setBare(true).setDirectory(f).call();
```

Then I push a branch to the repository(we call it pushA). I stored the old Object Id and new object id in the database.
Now I want to see all commits of pushA. So I got commits from old Object Id to new object id.

```
commits = command.addRange(r.resolve(since), r.resolve(until)).call();
```

here, since is the old object id, until id the new object id.
Then we have the exception:

```
Missing commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I find that the old object id of pushA is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. What shall I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get commits like this:

```
commits = command.add(r.resolve(until)).call();
```

so we can get all commits from start 00000000000000000000000 to until